# AWS launch template: A value of 4 for CoreCount is not a valid value for the r5a.xlarge instance type. Valid values are [2]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a launch template from a running graviton instance.  While saving the template, I changed the instance type from r5dg.xlarge to r5a.xlarge, and changed the ubuntu AMI to the x86 edition.

When I attempt to launch an instance from this template, I get the following error:

```
A value of 4 for CoreCount is not a valid value for the r5a.xlarge instance type. Valid values are [2].
```

There's no place to edit the core count.

Answer (score 7):

I've faced same issue today, trying to downgrade from `t3.xlarge` to `t3.large`, and it seems that it is normal behaviour; as the Launch Template is created with the number of cores from the initial selected type of instance; and its value is not updated when new instance type is selected.

It is not an issue if you go with a more powerful instance, as it will have enough cores for running previous configuration (although you will be not taking profit from new cores availables in your instance); but when downgrading to a less powerful instance, it is a problem and you need to modify this value.

As you pointed, it is not possible to modify `CoreCount` from AWS Console, so you have to edit it through AWS CLI (updating the [CpuOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-launch-template-version.html) property), for instance like:

```
aws ec2 create-launch-template-version --region YOUR_REGION --launch-template-id YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID --source-version TEMPLATE_VERSION_TO_UPDATE --launch-template-data '{"CpuOptions": {"CoreCount": NUMBER_OF_CORES_TO_USE, "ThreadsPerCore": THREADS_PER_CORE}}'
```

In your case, `NUMBER_OF_CORES_TO_USE` should be 2, and `THREADS_PER_CORE` could be 1 or 2, as you prefer (2 by default). Once modified, it will work again as expected

Comment: My template was based on t3.small and I migrated to t4g.small, so ThreadsPerCore had to go from 2 to 1, and this solution worked for me. Thanks.